70s\80s thriller where a girl's family members die one by one
This movie is about a family who starts having mysterious deaths. Starting with Grandma being frightened to death by an iguana in her bed. Then the brother falls of the roof trying to get a Frisbee, then the dad is electrocuted in the bathtub, and it turns out the little girl is possessed by her dead twin sister and she is responsible. What is the name of this movie. Please help its driving me crazy! 

Don't Go To Sleep with Dennis Weaver and Valerie Harper from 1982.

A young girl (Mary) and her family move into a new home along with her Grandmother. The Family have recently been recovering from the loss of their daughter (Jennifer). During the family's stay, They are attacked by the spirit of Jennifer, mostly taunting Mary. The family are subject to Mary being under the influence of Jennifer and are slowly picked off one by one... 

...in the exact ways you've described. Here's a clip:




OMG Thank you so much! This is exactly the movie! Thank you thank you thank you!
